# Why is this a ReadOnly record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I am building an associated object through a main object like so:
`item.associated_items.build({name: "Machine", color: "Grey"})`

and then in another method calling `item.save`. However I am getting an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` error. I read in the docs that

> Records loaded through joins with piggy-back attributes will be marked as read only since they cannot be saved.

so I think that is what is happening here. But

1. I dont't know why that is happening. I have called save on an object with a new associated record before and had no problems.
2. What do the docs mean when they say "piggy-back attributes"?
3. Is there a way to make the save happen by doing something like `item.associated_items.readonly(false).build(attributes)`. I tried that and it didnt work, but I'm hoping there is another way.

edit: I just tried
`new_associated_item = AssociatedItem.new({attributes})`
`item.associated_items << new_associated_item`

and the later method calls
`item.save`
and the read only exception still happens.

edit2: MurifoX asked me about how Item is being loaded. The above code is happening in a couple of service objects. The process is

Controller

```
owner = Owner.includes(:medallions).references(:medallions).find_by_id(params[:id])
```

later

```
creator = NoticeCreator.new(owner)
creator.run
```

NoticeCreator

```
def initialize #effectively
    medallion_notice_creators = []
    owner.medallions.some_medallion_scope.each do |medallion|
        medallion_notice_creator = MedallionNoticeCreator.new(medallion)
        medallion_notice_creator.prepare
        medallion_notice_creators << medallion_notice_creator
    end
end
```

later after looping through the medallion notice creators

```
def prepare
    medallion.notices.build(attributes)
end
```

later

```
medallion_notice_creators.each do |medallion_notice_creator|
    medallion_notice_creator.medallion.save
end
```

Apologies if the code seems convoluted. There is a bunch of stuff going on and I'm trying to condense the code and anonymize it.

Comment: How are you creating/finding `item`? Is it with a `join` query? `(Item.joins(:something))` or `(Item.find(id))`.

Comment: @MurifoX I'll edit my question with the full object loading cycle.

Comment: @MurifoX added object load path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects created with `joins` or `includes`, which is your case, are marked read-only because you are making a giant query with joins and stuff and preloading nested objects within your main one. (`ActiveRecord` can become confused with so many attributes and don't know how to build the main object, so it marks `readonly` on it.)

As you have noticed, this won't happen if you create you object with a simple `find`, as the only attributes received from the query are from the object itself.

I don't know why you are eager loading all of this associations, maybe it is from some rule in your code, but you should try to create a simple `owner` object using `Owner.find(params[:id])`, and lazy loading the associations when needed, so this way you can build nested associations on the simple object and save them.

Comment: So I stripped out the eager loading from the controller method, it now looks like Owner.find_by_id(params[:id]), but I seem to have hit the same error. Could it be caused by the `owner.medallions.medallion_scope` call?

Comment: Probably yes, you need a bare bones object to be saved.

Comment: The thing is I've been able to call save on an object and all associated objects that were created off of the object will also be saved. It may just be that I am loading too many objects off of others. But it feels odd to have to do a find to look up the objects I already have access to.